# jlabel prints string but not variable

Tags: java, string, jlabel, println

The issue is that I try to update the Jlabel with a String from a variable, but only the String typed directly is printed, not the variable.
In another program it works and I couldn't see the difference.

```
while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
  st2 = st1.nextToken();
 } 
 label.setText("Print: " + st2); //System.out.println(st2);
 writeToFile(st2);
```

Comment: what is St2 for a data Type??

Comment: String, but comes from few 3-4 lines of html.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it depends on how the String is parsed thru the variable.
If you add an + to the = sign it concatenate the parsed String.

Thanks

```
st2 += st1.nextToken();
```

Comment: didn't see that also you could do st2 = st1.nextToken().toString(); or st2 = ""+st1.nextToken();

Comment: Yes I tried also the two and seems it doesn't work too. Only +=, the Problem is that now it prints more Strings, but at least just one in the JLabel.

Comment: i guess you have some value stored previously in st2 , thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Yes some other values are restrained with the StringTokenizer. Thank you too